# For a velocity field of an ideal fluid $u$, show that that is an incompressible fluid and satisfies the correct boundary condition in a long box

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, boundary-conditions

The velocity field of an ideal fluid is given by:

> [image: Blockquote]

We need to show Show that this is an incompressible fluid and that its satisfies the correct boundary condition in a long box:

> [image: Blockquote]

We can show that it is uncompressible fluid by:

> [image: Blockquote]

Now to prove that the boundary condition:

A diagram of the boundary condition is:

> [image: Blockquote]

Now to show for all sides:

> [image: Blockquote]

this is where i am having trouble. For $y=0$ is the normal vector $n\bf{\hat{y}} $ or $n\bf{\hat{-y}} $

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use dot products to show the flow matches the boundary conditions, we can simply consider the appropriate part of the expression for $\boldsymbol{u}$.

In the $x$-direction, we need the flow velocity to be zero when $x=a$ and $x=-a$. Setting $x$ to that value, we see that $\boldsymbol{u}$ only has a component in the $y$-direction, so there is no flow through the side walls. Likewise, setting $y=0$ and $y=2a$ we see that $\boldsymbol{u}$ only has a component in the $x$-direction, so there is no flow through the top and bottom walls. Together, this means that the no penetration boundary conditions are met.